# HTML: Why is the text one paragraph lower than the image? (With picture)

Tags: html, css

I am having the following issue:

This is the result I am getting currently:

[image]

It is produced by this HTML code:

```css
.box-2 /*targeting class from HTML*/
    {
     border:8px dotted #ccc;
    }
```

```html
<!--Who we are-->
<div id="whoweare" align="center" class="box-2">
  <div align="center> 
    <font color="#534f4f" size="+1"> 
      <h1 id="txt_whoweare_headline">Who we are</h1>
    </font>
  </div>
  <div style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px"> 
    <table border="0">
      <tr> <!--tablerow-->
        <th width=400px>
          <div align="center"> 
            <img 
              src="./img/me.png"
              width=60%> 
          </div>
        </th> 
        <td width=400px>
          <div align="justify">        
            <font color="#534f4f" size="+2" > 
              <h3>Julius Tolksdorf</h3>
              <div id="txt_whoweare_body1">CEO of innomotion media and head of software development.</div> 
              <div id="txt_whoweare_body2">
                He will be your primary contact during the planning and development processes.
                Julius has already finished about 20 apps, games & web pages and has years of experience being an Android & Unity developer.
              </div>
            </font>
          </div>
        </td> 
      </tr> <!--for padding-->
        <tr height=20px/>
      </tr>

    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can probably see, the Text saying "JULIUS TOLKSDORF" starts one line lower than the image to the left. Of course I wish for both of them to start from the same line. 
The CSS is just this:

```
.box-2 /*targeting class from HTML*/
{
    border:8px dotted #ccc;
}
```

I would appreciate, If someone was to guide me towards fixing said issue.

Thank yoU:)

Comment: Header-elements have default margin set by the browser, try h3 {margin-top: 0;}

Comment: you mean to override h3 from css? i tried this, it didnt really change anything... but I believe you are onto something ...

Comment: a sorry. I "corrected" yours saying: .h3 but it was actually just h3... THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Header tags have a margin by default, so your `<h3>` also has this margin. The solution to your problem would be to set the `margin` to 0 on the top.

The code for this would be similar to:

```
h3 {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

NOTE: this would remove the top margin of ALL the h3 elements in the page.

Comment: Also when the image is higher than the text, you should have `style="vertical-align: top;"` at the `<td>` containing the text.

Answer (score 1):

The browser adds user agent styles to HTML tags. In this case the `<h3>` has the following styles added;

```
h3 {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.17em;
    margin-block-start: 1em;
    margin-block-end: 1em;
    margin-inline-start: 0px;
    margin-inline-end: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

If you set the `h3 { margin: 0; }`, it should bring the image and `<h3>` inline.

You are also missing a closing " on your second div; so this `<div align="center>`
should be this `<div align="center">`

Comment: @user11480561 actually, regarding the `align` attribute, you're a research away... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes

Answer (score -1):

The Text saying "JULIUS TOLKSDORF" is actually have some margin by default, you need to set margin-top with value 0 in `<h3>` tag

```
<h3 style="margin-top: 0;">Julius Tolksdorf</h3>
```

Comment: The "inline styles" method isn't really recommended other than in HTML email.  CSS styles should be in the `<head>` or preferably in external CSS files.